# How to close opened NotesDatabase and NotesSession?

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

How to close the testSession and testDatabase ? Once all operation has been finished with the database and session. I can see only Open method is there in NotesDatabase and there is no Close method.

```
NotesSession testSession = new NotesSession();
testSession.Initialize("password");

NotesDatabase testDatabase = testSession.GetDatabase("servername", "names.nsf", false);
```

Comment: you don't need to close the session.

Comment: @TorstenLink Thank You. how to close the NotesDatabase ?

Comment: And you do not need to close the database

Comment: As I recall, when the objects go out of scope in C# code, they are cleaned up.  This is different from what happens with the equivalent Java objects (in the standard version of the API) where they need to be recycled in order to reclaim allocated storage.